# Como extrair o arquivo de log do SQL Server do servidor?

Tags: sql-server

Tenho um servidor SQL Server e preciso enviar o arquivo de Log para um de nossos Clientes, porém esse arqvuivo tem 24 gigabyte, dúvida:

Como extrair esse arquivo de logo no formato csv ?

Answer (score 0):

Comando de exemplo para reduzir o arquivo de log do Sql Server

```
alter database sh_rodov01
set recovery simple
dbcc shrinkfile (sh_rodov01_log, 10)
alter database sh_rodov01
set recovery full
```